# var_export prettifier / visualizer

Tags: php

I'm using var_export to dump output to logs when errors occur. However since the result is in pure text, I don't get a chance to push it through some sort of library like krumo so I can interactively explores the output.

What methods do people have to deal with making var_export text more readable?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function, it works well for multidimensional arrays:

```
function VE($varname, $varval, $short_syntax=true, $tag = '    ', $comma='', $end_line="\r\n") {
    $res = '';
    if($short_syntax){
        $begin_array = '[';
        $end_array = ']';
    } else {
        $begin_array = 'array(';
        $end_array = ')';
    }
    $arr = explode('/',$varname); 
    $dim =count($arr)-1; 
    $lastKey = end($arr);
    if (! is_array($varval)){
        if( is_string($varval)) $varval = "'$varval'";
        $res .= str_repeat($tag,$dim) . $lastKey . ' => ' . $varval . $comma . $end_line;
    }else{

        $res .= str_repeat($tag,$dim) . $lastKey . ' => ' . $begin_array . $end_line;
        $count_varval = 0;
        $dim_varval = count($varval);
        foreach ($varval as $key => $val){
            $count_varval++;
            if($count_varval<$dim_varval) $commma=','; else $commma='';
            if( is_string($key)) $key = "'$key'";
            $res .= VE ($varname . "/" . $key , $val, $short_syntax, $tag, $commma);
        }
        $res .= str_repeat($tag,$dim) . $end_array . $comma . $end_line;
    }
    return $res;
}
$bigarray = array(); // your array
$bb = VE ('$bigarray', $bigarray);
echo "<pre>$bb</pre>";
```

I hope it helps ;)